# How do I handle hebrew and english text in inkscape

Tags: svg, inkscape

I have created a svg file with inkscape that contains english and hebrew text. Both the english and the hebrew text flow to the right (correct) direction when the svg is opened in the inkscape editor. However, if the same svg file is opened in firefox, the hebrew text flows from left to right (as does the english text) which is the opposite direction as in inkscape and not what I want.

So, is this behaviour expected or a bug?

I have tried to manually change the attribute `writing-mode` from `lr-tb` to `rl-tb` on the hebrew text, but that has no visible influence on the rendering of text, at least not to me.

I'd appreciate any help on how I can display the created svg file 'correctly' in a web browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the writing-mode attribute is not currently supported in Firefox's implementation of SVG: https://developer.mozilla.org/En/SVG_in_Firefox